# Is a partially frozen chicken safe if not immediately cooked at the proper temperature?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I put a partially frozen (inside) chicken in my convection oven, set it to what I thought was 400ºF (200ºC) and left the room with a timer on. An hour later it was discovered the temperature was only 150-200ºF (65-93ºC). It was in the convection oven an hour! I quickly set the correct temperature and finished cooking it. I just don't know if the hour it spent in the convection oven on the lower temperature did something with bacteria. I cooked it to an internal temperature of 180ºF (80ºC) degrees. Is it safe to eat this chicken?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've edited your question to be a little more clear. I strongly suspect that there's a question here that already answers this, but I can't find a good one right now. We do have good questions about [proper defrosting](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3472/1672), [how long you can leave meat at room temperature](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15557/1672), and even [cooking frozen meat](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/is-it-bad-to-cook-frozen-meat-without-waiting-it-to-be-unfrozen).

Comment: See [this question about cooking chicken at a low temperature for a long time](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12408/1549) and [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6032/1549).

Comment: This situation is a bit different because it's a *convection* oven, so it will heat the surfaces much better than a normal oven, avoiding some of the safety concerns at lower temperatures (similar to sous-vide).

Comment: @Jefromi Sure, didn't mean to imply they are duplicates. Actually [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/29830/1549) has better information than the last two links I posted, although once again, not aimed specifically at frozen chicken or convection ovens.

Comment: How did the chicken get partially thawed?  If it spent little time in the fridge and straight to the oven ride you explained, then @ChrisSteinbach is right, and you should be fine.  The extra time spent transitioning through the danger zone isn't alarming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a problem with defrosting meat on the counter?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-there-a-problem-with-defrosting-meat-on-the-counter)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you thawed the chicken (to the extent that you did) in the refrigerator, and further assuming that it took less than an hour to reach a safe internal temperature, I would say you are fine. An internal temperature of 180ºF (80ºC) is safe by quite a margin.

The [USDA](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/PDF/Danger_Zone.pdf) recommends that home cooks do not keep food within the "Danger Zone" of 40-140ºF (4-60ºC) for more than 2 hours. This includes preparation *and* cooking time. If you thawed the bird on the kitchen counter, or if your chicken accompanied you on a long journey from the supermarket in an unfrozen state, you'll have to factor that time in.

As @Jefromi's comment on another answer notes, simply reaching a high enough internal temperature is not a guarantee of safety since some microbes produce [toxins that are heat-stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-stable_enterotoxin).

Answer (score -2):

No, do not eat food that has slowly passed through the danger zone.

In my food handler classes I learned that any food that quickly moves from HOT --> Cold is safe, and visa versa.  However, it is un-safe to eat food that has slowly moved through the temperature zones.

IMO eat at your own risk.

edit for corrections

Comment: The danger zone is from 40F to 140F, and even the initial baking temperature was above this.